# NoScript extension redirects page

Tags: firefox

I am trying to access a web api with URL:

```
http://example.com/path/to/my.php
```

I am able to access the web api itself with the URL above or even when I add some parameters like

```
http://example.com/path/to/my.php?a=1
http://example.com/path/to/my.php?documentId=
```

The problem is when I try to access

```
http://example.com/path/to/my.php?documentId=1
```

the page gets redirected to:

```
http://example.com/#029413641551195635400
```

How do I prevent NoScript from redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by NoScript's XSS feature.
Somehow NoScript thinks your request is an XSS attempt.

To fix the problem, add your URL in NoScript's Options > Advanced > XSS > Anti-XSS Protection Exceptions:

```
^http://example.com/.*$
```